# Variable resets when leaving class file

Tags: c++

I'm practicing c++ by making a hangman game. The problem is that when I set the hangman word in a class file and then move to another class file,  I find that it has been reset. When I call the variable, it's empty.

I have tried using a reference instead of the standard variable, as I understand that when you call a function, it only creates copies of the variables. I have another buildGame.h and buildGame.cpp file, but all they do is call the getPhrase(); function. This is where I discover that the variable is reset, and doesn't hold the phrase value.

This is my main.cpp file: v

```
#include "genGame.h"
#include "buildGame.h"

int main(){
    genGame startGame;
    buildGame build;
    startGame.genPhrase();
    buildGame();
    return 0;
}
```

This is my genGame.h file: v

```
#ifndef GENGAME_H
#define GENGAME_H
#include <string>

class genGame{
    public:
        genGame();
        void genPhrase();
        std::string getPhrase() const;

    private:
        std::string phrase;
        int randnumb;
};

#endif
```

This is my gengame.cpp file: v

```
#include "genGame.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<time.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

genGame::genGame(){}

string genGame::getPhrase() const{
    cout << phrase << endl;     //included for testing purposes
    return phrase;
}

void genGame::genPhrase(){
    cout << "Welcome to hangman!" << endl;
    string& phraseRef = phrase;     //tried setting a reference to change the variable itself, not just the copy
    srand(time(0));
    randnumb = rand() % 852 + 1;    //random number to determine which word will be pulled out of 852 words
    ifstream wordlist ("wordlist.txt");     //list of hangman words

    if (wordlist.is_open()){
        for (int i = 1; i <= randnumb; i++){
            getline(wordlist, phraseRef);       //get the word, set it equal to the phrase variable
        }
        wordlist.close();
    }

    cout << phraseRef << endl;      //output word choice for testing purposes
    cin.get();

}
```

When calling the phrase variable outside the class, I expect it to return the set phrase. It instead returns the default empty value.

EDIT: Thank you paddy for the help! The answer is in his comment, and the code is working now (I wasn't correctly passing by reference).

Comment: Where are you initializing the value of phrase?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I suspect that you're looking at two different objects,

Comment: BTW: your code being located in separate files is completely irrelevant.

Comment: What does this line print `cout << phraseRef << endl;` in a sample run where `randnumb = 1`? You can hardcode that to check that out. Also, add a smaller words list here in your question say 10 words and adjust your `rand()` accordingly.

Comment: phrase is being initialized in the `getGame.h` file. It is then being modified by reference in the `genGame.cpp` file. Even if I replace `cout << phrase << endl;` with `cout << phraseRef << endl;` , the result is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have another buildGame.h and buildGame.cpp file, but all they do is call the getPhrase(); function. This is where I discover that the variable is reset, and doesn't hold the phrase value.

With your code as currently written, I don't even need to see the `buildGame` class to answer.  It is impossible for either of the two `buildGame` objects <sup>(†)</sup> that you create in `main` to have any knowledge of the `genGame` object also created in `main`.

If you need to make the object identified as `startGame` available to a member function or similar in a `buildGame` object, you need to pass it as a reference.  For example, you might have this:

```
void buildGame::play(const genGame &startGame)
{
    std::cout << "Playing with phrase: " << startGame.getPhrase() << std::endl;
}
```

And in `main`, you would perhaps do this:

```
int main()
{
    genGame startGame;
    buildGame build;
    startGame.genPhrase();
    build.play(startGame);  // <=== pass reference to startGame
    return 0;
}
```

However you *thought* you were accessing `startGame` in your original code, you were mistaken.

---

(†) : Yes, you created two `buildGame` objects:

```
buildGame build;  // This constructs a buildGame identified as 'build'
buildGame();      // This constructs a buildGame and then destroys it
```

Comment: You're a gentleman/gentlewoman and a scholar. Thank you so much! This makes a lot of sense now, and I learned a lot from your post. The code is working now :)

Comment: You're welcome.  You should consider accepting the answer.  Looking at your profile, I see other posts where you have received good answers and have not accepted them.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)